# is there a concept of Shortcuts/Alias/Pointer in R?

Tags: r

I am working on a rather large dataset in R which is split in several dataframes.

The problem is that I do some things with the whole set, sometimes I just need to work with or modify parts of the set and my selectors are getting very clunky, f.e.

```
aListOfItems$attribute4([aListOfItems$attribute1 == true & aListOfItems$attribute2 == 6
& aListOfItems$attribute3 == "C"),] <- aListOfItems([aListOfItems$attribute1 == true &   
aListOfItems$attribute2 == 6 & aListOfItems$attribute3 == "C"),aListOfItems$attribute5]
* aListOfItems([aListOfItems$attribute1 == true & aListOfItems$attribute2 == 6 &
aListOfItems$attribute3 == "C"),aListOfItems$attribute7]
```

(this sets attribute 4 to (attribute5 * attribute6) for a *selected* part of all entries.)

This is horrible to read, understand and edit.

Splitting these into a different dataframes is not really an option due to RAM and because I refresh this data regulary and rebuilding all the seperate dataframes would also be a pain.

So, is there any way to do something like

```
items_t6C <- &(aListOfItems([aListOfItems$attribute1 == true & aListOfItems$attribute2
 == 6 & aListOfItems$attribute3 == "C"),]
```

so I can use

```
items_t6C$attribute4 <- # do something
```

Alternatively, maybe it is possible to store such a selector in a string-variable and use it?

Comment: For a start, look into `with` and `within` commands in R. It will help you get rid of need to type `aListOfItems$` so many times

Comment: In addition, if `attribute1` is a logical, the `== true` is not needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can first construct a logical vector, give it a meaningful name, and use that in the command. It makes your script a bit longer, but much easier to read:

```
interesting_bit = with(aListOfItems, attribute1 &   
                                     attribute2 == 6 & 
                                     attribute3 == "C")
```

In addition, using a bit of indentation also makes the code much more readable.

```
aListOfItems$attribute4[interesting_bit,] <- 
     aListOfItems[interesting_bit,aListOfItems$attribute5]
   * aListOfItems[interesting_bit,aListOfItems$attribute7]
```

And using `within` does more for readability:

```
aListOfItems[interesting_bit,] = within(aListOfItems[interesting_bit,], {
      attribute4 = attribute5 * attribute7
   }
```

Also, for a logical there is no need to explicitly test for `== true`:

```
interesting_bit = aListOfItems$attribute1 &   
         aListOfItems$attribute2 == 6 & aListOfItems$attribute3 == "C"
```

This ultimately reduces this:

```
aListOfItems$attribute4([aListOfItems$attribute1 == true & aListOfItems$attribute2 == 6
& aListOfItems$attribute3 == "C"),] <- aListOfItems([aListOfItems$attribute1 == true &   
aListOfItems$attribute2 == 6 & aListOfItems$attribute3 == "C"),aListOfItems$attribute5]
* aListOfItems([aListOfItems$attribute1 == true & aListOfItems$attribute2 == 6 &
aListOfItems$attribute3 == "C"),aListOfItems$attribute7]
```

to this (note the additional use of `with`):

```
interesting_bit = with(aListOfItems, attribute1 &   
                                     attribute2 == 6 & 
                                     attribute3 == "C")
aListOfItems[interesting_bit,] = within(aListOfItems[interesting_bit,], {
      attribute4 = attribute5 * attribute7
   }
```

This code does not only look less daunting, but also instantly conveys what it is you are doing, which is very hard to divine from your original code.

Comment: Assignment is not necessary if you are using `within`. OTOH if you **need** to do some assignment then you probably will need to use `with`

Comment: To get the assignment back to the orignal object, I think you do need to perform the assignment. If not, the result will just be printed to the screen.

Comment: Assignment is necessary. Thanks for the great answer, that really helps me a lot.

Comment: I added even more reduction using with.

Answer (score 3):

The `data.table` package might be useful to you.

`data.table` works mostly by reference. Especially when assigning and modifying columns. 
Especially if you are hitting RAM limits, the efficiencies in data.table are dramatic

Additionally, data.table has built into the functionality of `with` `within` `by` `subset` etc, making calls much shorter and code more readable.

For example, the cummbersome statement above could be simplified to something like:

```
aDTofItems[attribute1 & attribute2==6 & attribute3=="C", # filter
           attribute4 := attribute5 * attribute6]        # assign
```

Furthermore, if the attributes you are filtering on are the `key` of the table, then the line is even shorter:

```
aDTofItems[.(TRUE, 6, "C"),     # filter
           attribute4 := attribute5 * attribute6]   # assign
```

Assuming the structure of each element is comparable, you can coerce your list into a data.table using

```
aDTofItems <- rbindlist(aListOfItems)
# note, if you have factors in your list you should convert them to character before calling rbindlist

# or similarly, although a bit slower 
aDTofItems <- data.table(do.call(rbind, aListOfItems))
```

Comment: Oh, very interesting approach aswell, thank you. I will try data.table.

Comment: @racoonie, please do, and let us know how it goes.

Comment: So I tried and I have to say that the inability to use factors in data.tables was a dealbreaker for me, I am using quite some of them in my dataset. But I will keep it in mind for future reference. Thanks again!

Comment: @racoonie, hmmm... how specifically are you trying to use factors that you find you are not able to?

Comment: The biggest reason is speed and memory, some operations that I did with factors were taking a much longer time when using data.tables.